# How can I transpose some specific columns, while repeating first 4 columns using a formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unpivot

I would need the first 4 columns to have their data repeated, while the others are stacked up, like the example below and whose link can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit#gid=1255157842):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  LET(F;LAMBDA(x;FILTER(x;A2:A<>""));
      SPLIT(TOCOL(F(A2:A)&"|"&F(B2:B)&"|"&F(C2:C)&"|"&F(D2:D)&"|"&E1:G1&"|"&F(E2:G));"|")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(;1);E2:G6;lambda(a;c;vstack(a;hstack(index(A1:D6;row(c));index(A1:G1;column(c));c))))
```

[image]

***UPDATED FORMULA***:

```js
=reduce(tocol(;1);E2:index(G:G;match(;0/(A:A<>"")));lambda(a;c;vstack(a;hstack(index(A:D;row(c));index(A1:G1;column(c));c))))
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot! Since there will be future data added to the set, I am trying to use it with open ended ranges, but it gets really slow to the point it breaks.

Comment: try the updated formula which is set to pick just the data rows.